# Как можно легко просмотреть зависимость кода?

Tags: php

Допустим я переписываю часть какого либо функционала, при этом остается старый код который по правильному нужно было бы удалить. Но возможна такая ситуация, что его удаление затронет другую часть системы. Как можно просто просматривать зависимость одного кода от другого, что бы вручную не тестировать весь функционал на наличие работоспособности?

Comment: В общем случае это невозможно, такой уж этот пхп, да и другие интерпретируемые языки. В частном — я бы с помощью `grep`'а искал нужные названия переменных, классов и функций

Comment: тестировать автоматически?

Comment: Тестировать не протестируете, как вариант, искать где используется та или иная функция

Comment: @vp_arth ну это ещё тесты должны быть))

Comment: а так только юнит тестирование

Comment: @vp_arth ну хотелось бы некую программу, скажем удаляешь функцию а она в фоновом режиме сканит каталог на наличие индификаторов в других файлах и если они есть то предупреждает об этом. это я так скажем упрощенный вариант описал

Comment: Используйте phpunit или codeception для написания тестов к вашему приложению. И замените блокнот на IDE, сам пользую PhpStorm.

Comment: в PhpStorm есть "Find Usage" вот по нему можно искать (ALT+ F7)

Comment: Если у вас нормальный диалект php(не php4/5.2), вам может помочь любая из флагманских IDE, там есть функции а-ля "Find Usages"

Comment: @vp_arth вот вот можно быстро и дешево определить где используется функция

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick дешево? вы уверены? phpstorm не фриварный

Comment: @perfect, Eclipse, NetBeans, ... Тысячи их

Answer (score 2):

С поиском, используется ли код где-либо, есть фундаментальная проблема - динамический вызов кода. Например, метод контроллера в MVC обычно нигде явно не вызывается, а определяется и вызывается динамически. Поэтому даже если точку входа найти не удалось, гарантировать, что код не используется - нельзя. Как-нибудь хитро он всё ещё может вызываться.

С учётом этой особенности можно использовать какой-либо статический анализатор кода. Например, [phan](https://github.com/etsy/phan). Для работы phan потребует php7, но анализировать исходник можно и для более старых версий, заодно можете получить предупреждения несовместимости. Для проверки конкретного метода на использование можно добавить этому методу аннотацию `@deprecated` (или же сразу удалить метод) и посмотреть отчёт анализатора - если нет предупреждений, значит анализатор не нашёл случаев использования.

Перед удалением кода и с отсутствием уверенности, что этот код никто больше не вызывает я бы порекомендовал в начале код добавить логирование вызова с сохранением трассировки вызова (штатная функция `debug_backtrace`) и оставить на какое-то время в продакшене. Если за разумный срок (месяц, два, год - смотря что за код) в логе не появились сообщения - то код уже можно вычищать. В случае чего можно же будет из системы контроля версий достать.

Comment: спасибо мелкий. возьму на вооружение. только вот в продакшене не получится оставить. а так то что нужно. хотя ведь существует возможность что некий метод могут запустить и через два года и система вообще может обвалится )

Comment: Такой риск останется всегда. Чтобы его не было - надо запретить вообще менять код, любой, даже если эти изменения хочет бизнес.